# Can I set a field value in my custom elasticsearch analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin

I'm implementing an elasticsearch analyzer plug-in.

It takes a document and extract terms to be indexed, and also classifies the document
into one of pre-defiend categories.

Here, I faced a problem for the latter.
See the following index.

```
{Id: string, Content: string, Category1: boolean, Category2: boolean}
```

As the classification result for '***content***', *Category1* or *Category2* should be set to true.
But I couldn't find any way to set a field value in my analyzer plug-in code.

Is there anyone who can help me?
How can I do this?